# Use libpng to resize (bicubic) a list of images

Tags: c++, qt, libpng

Can someone point me to a tutorial where it is explained how to use libpng & png++ for applying bicubic resizing on images? I have spent almost three hours looking for something and cannot find. Perhaps because I don't know where to look.

The image ([48 bit image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/48-bit#Images)) is read with `libpng` and then read into a `QImage` for output. If I use `QImage::scaled` on the image, the pixel information is lost and the image is not useful for what I need it.

I read and manipulate an image with png::rgba_pixel_16 pixel - reading it like this:

`png::image< png::rgba_pixel_16 > myImage(myFile.toAscii());`

Quoting another answer:

> there is no 16 bits per component format in QImage. The most you can get is QImage::Format_ARGB32 at 8 bits per component. Even if you used 8 bits indexed mode, the color tables do not support more than 8 bits per component. Moreover, the QImageIOHandler class works in terms of QImage, so you cannot create a custom image format plug-in to work with 16 bits per color component, unfortunately.

The last quote explains why I can't use QImage for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to resize an image programmatically, take a look at [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

Comment: Thanks, but need to use QT for this.

Comment: Qt doesn't support 48bpp images. AFAICT after a quick glance at the documentation libpng cannot do scaling. What does it mean that you "need to use Qt for this"? Use Qt to call imagemagick :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need libpng with Qt.

Just use

```
QImage QImage::scaled ( const QSize & size, Qt::AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode, Qt::TransformationMode transformMode ) const
```

with `transformMode = Qt::SmoothTransformation` for bilinear scaling.

Comment: I know, I tried this already but, for some reason, it didn't gave me the expected results. I think it has to be with bit depths.

Comment: What was precisely the issue? Might be interesting to open a question for this...

Comment: The image (48 bit image) is read with libpng and then read into a `QImage` for output. If I use `QImage::scaled` on the image, the pixel information is lost and the image is not useful for what I need it.

Comment: The question asks about bicubic, not bilinear scaling. I was hoping to find an answer for doing this with Qt, but I'm starting to think that there isn't one, beyond using a third party api like OpenCV to perform the scaling, and then converting to QImage.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need libpng? You could just read the image in a array and then perform resizing on that, you don't need libpng, after reading the image it becomes independent of the format...

Comment: I read and manipulate an image with png::rgba_pixel_16 pixel - reading it like this: png::image< png::rgba_pixel_16 > myImage(myFile.toAscii());   This gives me the quality I need (I think is 64 bits??, but am not sure, the thing is that the result is ok, but too big.)